# Reading 'ahead' and moving back in an algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

So, I'm trying to 'mimic' a file format that can consist of the following data:

```
0x64-0xFB(100-251):A single byte consisting of a value (byteval-100)
0xFC(252): A 'null' byte, I don't need anything with that
0xFD(253): An indicator that I need to 'read ahead', more information follows
0xFE(254): Another 'null' byte in this case
```

These values are all grouped in blocks of 8 bytes until `EOF` occurs.

When a `0xFD` value occurs, I need to move to the next block of 8 bytes, and read a value there. After I read this, I will need to move to the next byte (and skip the next block, because I already read it). For this instance this will be a 64-bit float (or a double, for that matter). An example here:

`0x71 0x75 0xFD 0x6E 0x78 0x82 0x8C 0x72`

`0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0xC0 0x82 0x40`

Will be the following values (in order)

```
13 (0x71 - 100)
17 (0x75 - 100)
600.0 (the value of 0x0000000000C08240 in double, because of the 0xFD)
10 (0x6E - 100)
20 (0x78 - 100)
30 (0x82 - 100)
40 (0x8C - 100)
14 (0x72 - 100)
```

The `0xFD` may occur multiple times in one block, indicating that the following blocks are all `double` blocks (so, if `0xFD` occurs two times, the following two blocks will be double blocks and will need to be 'read ahead').

I've tried programming this, but I can't think of a viable solution for this (that's also a tad efficient). I tried making a list of 'long value blocks', and that when I stepped into a long data block, I would just skip it. I would also need to return to the next 'normal' data after I read the long data block. But, this will introduce all kind of technical difficulties.

I'm sure there's some simple solution to this, but I just can't get my head around it.

Anyone has any ideas? Feel free to answer in pseudocode, or any programming language for that matter. I just need the basic principle of how to approach this.

The following code is what I came up with (in Javascript):

```
    readNumber: function() {
        opcode = this.getNextOpcode();      
        switch(opcode) {
            case -1:
            case 252:
            return null;
            case 253:
            return this.readNextFloat(this.position);
            case 255:
                return null; //SYSMIS
                default:
                return opcode - this.header.bias;
            }
        },
    getNextOpcode: function() {
        if(_.contains(this.longdatablocks,this.getCurrentBlock())) {
            gotoBlock(_.max(this.longdatablocks) + 1);
            return this.rU8();
        }
        return this.rU8();
    },
    readNextFloat: function(position) {
        this.gotoBlock(this.getnextBlock())
        console.debug(this.position);
        this.longdatablocks.push(this.getCurrentBlock());
        retval = this.rF64();
        this.position = position;
        return retval;
    },
```

This doesn't handle it very well, though. Multiple `0xFD`'s aren't covered, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution in C. The idea:

- Read the file in 8 byte blocks. Once a block is read, keep it in an 8 byte array.
- Go through the 8 bytes of the current block (reading them from memory this time) and handle them 1 by 1
- Whenever 253 occurs, read 8 bytes from the file as a double and output it. No need to ever jump ahead or jump back, even with multiple 253s in the same block. Simply reading 8 byte blocks in order will give the correct output.

Code:

```
void parse(char *fname)
{
    FILE *f = fopen(fname, "rb");
    unsigned char *block = (unsigned char *)malloc(8); // allocate an 8 byte block of memory
    while (fread(block, 1, 8, f) == 8) // keep reading 8 bytes from the file to the memory block until EOF
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) // go through the block in memory, byte by byte
        {
            if (block[i] <= 251) printf("%d\n", block[i] - 100); // if the byte is <= 251, output value - 100
            else if (block[i] == 253) // otherwise, read 8 bytes from the file as a double and output it
            {
                double d;
                fread(&d, 1, 8, f);
                printf("%lf\n", d);
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
    free(block);
}
```

Comment: Pure love. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use two pointers - to current data block, and to potential float or data block, and increment latter when needed.

at the start of 8-byte block reading:

```
CurrentIndex = NextIndex
Next(Float)Index = CurrentIndex + 1
```

at the end of readNextFloat body:

```
Next(Float)Index++
```